# PayPalPro - Advanced

Tags: orders, cart, api

I'm using Magento 1.8.1 with PayPal Advanced. Orders taken when the user chooses their Paypal account are processed correctly. When a customer chooses to enter credit card information, a request is made and is approved by PayPal. I have verified this in my logs. PayPal states that a second request is made that is voiding the transaction, but I don't see a request in logs to actually void the transaction.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I'm stuck!

I have checked my PayPal settings and they haven't changed.
AVS: No
CSC: No
Enable Secure Token: Yes.

I am registering an exception in the exception logs... But I don't know how to debug it.

> 2015-04-21T17:44:47+00:00 ERR (3):  exception 'Mage_Core_Exception'
>   with message 'Invalid block type: ' in
>   /home/mystore/public_html/app/Mage.php:595 Stack trace:
>   0 /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495):
>   Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
>   1 /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('', Array)
>   2 /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('', 'checkout.cart')
>   3 /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('', 'checkout.cart')
>   4 /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element),
>   Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
>   5 /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
>   6 /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
>   7 /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
>   8 /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php(160): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout()
>   9 /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418):
>   Mage_Checkout_CartController->indexAction()
>   10 /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
>   11 /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
>   12 /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
>   13 /home/mystore/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
>   14 /home/mystore/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
>   15 {main}

Answer (score 0):

this is cause by a faulty layout file.
There is probably something wrong with you theme.
Look in your theme for something like this

```
<block name="checkout.cart"...
```

That should be

```
<reference name="checkout.cart"....
```